# Auto update for MSI Package in WCF

Tags: c#, wcf, iis, deployment, windows-installer

I Have a scenario something like this...

i created a msi package to host the wcf service in iis. when ever there is any changes in the service i am uninstalling the package and creating a new one and then installoing back again.

Is there a possible way where we can auto update the MSI Package when ever there is a change in the wcf service.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you take a look at MSDeploy / Web Deploy 2.0 to deploy your services instead, it's far more suited for the job.

http://www.iis.net/download/WebDeploy

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa751792.aspx